# Idiomatic way to append an element in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Given the following JSX:

```
const elems = <div><p>hello</p><p>world</p></div>
```

If I want to add another element to the end, is there a more idiomatic way than doing:

```
const moreElems = <div>{elems}<p>additional</p></div>
```

Maybe something like:

```
elems.push(<p>additional</p>)
```

I would be fine omitting the wrapper `div`; that's just so there's only a single top-level JSX element.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do that by declaring the first elements in an array:

```
const elements = [
  <p>hello</p>,
  <p>world</p>,
]
```

And then pushing whatever you want to the array:

```
elements.push(<p>Additionnal</p>)
```

You can then use this element using `{elements}` anywhere you want.

Bear in mind that this array notation would require you to use a `key` parameter in each of these childs, so something like this would be better:

```
const elements = [
  <p key="1">hello</p>,
  <p key="2">world</p>,
]
elements.push(<p key="3">additionnal</p>)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always have them pushed into an array and then wrap the array in a div and react will handle it appropriately something like:

```
 const phrase = [];
 phrase.push(<p key="hello">hello</p><p>world</p>)
 phrase.push(<p key="additional">additional</p>)

 return <div> {phrase} </div>
```